# CXF client proxy how to handle certain response codes within the client

Tags: java, web-services, proxy, cxf

When I send a request using a proxy client, if I get a certain response, I would like to be able to modify the request and then send the same request again for all requests.

Normally I would do something like:

```
BookStore proxy = JAXRSClientFactory.create("http://books", BookStore.class);
try 
{
    proxy.getBook("someId");
} 
catch(WebApplicationException ex) 
{
    Response r = ex.getResponse();
    if (r.getStatusCode() == 404)
    {
       proxy.getBook("anotherId");
    }
}
```

But in this case, there is a common thing I want to do for all requests: If I get a specific http code, modify some header values, and then try again (probably with a limit on the amount of retries).

I haven't seen a way that cxf proxy clients explicitly support this, how could I go about implementing it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write an interceptor to do this for every request.
here you go for sample code and documentation http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-filters.html

Comment: I am aware of CXF interceptors. This is specifically for CXF proxies, and on the client-side rather than the server-side which is where interceptors are usually implemented.

Comment: No Man, Interceptors can be implemented client side as well. read the documentation and try something..http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html#JAX-RS-ClientAPI